# Roll up sum and if statement vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of products and their details. Row 2 is the headers, and from row 3 are the details. In column E, I have the quantities for each product and I have a total row at the bottom. Each week I get new data so the data range vary. The data has been sorted by quantity from largest to smallest.

Now my task is to find the row that has total quantities more than 65% of the total quantities we sold. That means I need to sum up each row in column E to determine which row will get me more than 65% of the total sales.

So I have written some vba codes but the results from my codes are just row3, the rest are deleted and there is no error. I am writing vba codes since this is part of the larger codes I have already written so I am only posting this portion of codes.

I have posted my data in picture but not the whole list since it's too long (with rows hidden) but you will get an idea of what I am trying to achieve. From this week's data, that means I will need to delete row 18 and below since row 17 is the first row that surpass the 65% mark. I don't need to display column J and K, I am just showing you what I mean by summing up the quantities and calculation for column percentages.

```
Sub test()
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim ValueA, ValueB As Variant
Dim lrE, c, d As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Zip")
lrE = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
d = sht.Range("E" & lrE)


For i = 3 To lrE - 1
    ValueA = 0.65
    ValueB = sht.Cells(i, 5).Value / d
          If ValueB <= ValueA Then
                ValueB = ValueB + sht.Cells(i, 5).Value
                i = i + 1
           End If
            If ValueB > ValueA Then
                c = sht.Cells(i, 5).Row
                    sht.Rows(c & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
            End If

   Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you just simple keep filling down your formula in `Column J` and stick in a formula at the top of your sheet that tells you which row breaches 65%? Like Formula = `=Match((0.65*SUM(C:C)),$J$3:$J$10000,1)+3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will find the first row that is 65% or greater and delete the rest.

```
Sub test()

Set sht = Worksheets("Zip")
lrE = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

tsum = WorksheetFunction.SUM(sht.Range(sht.Cells(3, 5), sht.Cells(lrE, 5)))

For i = 3 To lrE
 Sbtotal = Sbtotal + sht.Cells(i, 5).Value
    If Sbtotal / tsum > 0.65 Then
    LRow = i
    i = lrE + 1
    End If
Next i


sht.Rows(LRow + 1 & ":" & lrE).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, after running your codes, I am getting last row or row 53 deleted and the rest are still there. Not sure why.

Comment: I get it, you just need to change tsum formula a bit, change your sht.Cells(lrE, 5) to sht.Cells(lrE -1, 5). Then we get it. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't allow for your subtotal row , since this doesn't need the subtotal to be in the sheet.   Glad it worked for you.